# django test framework token authentication — is there any way to log everyone out?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I understand that token authentication doesnt really have the concept of logging out— that a token merely identifies a user.

Is there any way to invalidate all tokens? Maybe via the change of some variable from which all the tokens are generated— causing everyone to need to log in again?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends a bit on which auth system you are using. In case you are using `rest_framework.authtoken`, you could simply clear the `Token` table:

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
Token.objects.all().delete();
```

No token, not logged in ;)